# How to save the Image using node js rest api from the server

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working `nodejs and angular` and I am trying to download an image that I uploaded using nodejs (created a upload folder all the uploaded images are in server side upload folder), I already written an rest api but its not working.

let me explain the exact situation, there is a form for teacher for uploading the assignment he/she upload the assignment in the form of image now students can see the assignment uploaded by the teacher I also want to give the download option so the image can get download to the local machine.

I am using `mime-types` for this

**download api**

```
app.get("/download/:filename", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var imagename = req.params.filename;
  var file = __dirname + "/uploads/" + imagename;

  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  res.download(file)

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
})
```

from the angular side I am passing the object that contain name of the image that present in server side, folder name is upload

**service.ts**

(Right now I am passing the static name)

private downloadImageUrl = "http://localhost:3000/download/1592945165166-java-1.png";

```
  downloadImage(assignment: Assignment) {
    return this.http.get(this.downloadImageUrl, {
      observe: "body",
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
  onDownload(index: number) {
    console.log(this.assignment[index])
    this.teacherServ.downloadImage()
    .subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

I want to image get downloaded in the local system of download folder

No error message is there but still image is not downloaded to my local storage of download folder.

**UPDATE:**

I successfully able to save the image using the `file-saver` in `angular-7`, I will share the code here but still there is a one problem, problem is **jpg** format images are getting saved as a file format or an unknown format (basically I am unable to open it.), there is no problem with **png** format. So I want to how how can I save the jpg as well as png format of image using `file-saver`

**service.ts**

```
private downloadImageUrl = "http://localhost:3000/download";

  downloadImage(file: any){
      return this.http.post(this.downloadImageUrl, file, {
        responseType : 'blob',
        headers : new HttpHeaders().append('content-type','application/json')
      })
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<td>
  <img 
  height="92px" 
  style="cursor: pointer"
  src="http://localhost:3000/{{receivedAssignment.assignment}}" 
  alt="not found"
  (click)="onDownload(i)">
```

**component.ts**

```
onDownload(index: number) {
    console.log(this.assignment[index].assignment)
    var filename = this.assignment[index].filename
    this.teacherServ.downloadImage(this.assignment[index])  //sending the particular assignment that I want to download.
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            if(data && data != undefined && data != null) {
                saveAs(data, filename)
            }
        }
    )

}
```

**app.js** //nodejs api

```
app.post('/download', function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.body.assignment);
  console.log(path.join(__dirname,'uploads','/'+req.body.assignment))
  filepath = path.join(__dirname,'uploads','/'+req.body.assignment);
  res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

**So, this method is working for png images but not for jpg image, please let me know why? and how can I solve this?**

Thanks.

Comment: It helps if you tell people what those lines 49 and 53 map to, because they don't seem to map to any of the code you're actually showing. Also, downloading means getting data, whereas upload means posting data, so seeing a function called `downloadImage` that has code `http.post(...)` is very confusing and should probably be changed.

Comment: Thank you for replying I edited the question added the line number 53 part actually that is the response error, reason I am using the post method because I am passing the name of the image.

Comment: That's not really a good enough reason. Pass that as a normal url argument with standard API pathing (e.g. `/images/39/filtered?teacher=2&semester=5&...`), because the intended use of a POST operation is to _not generate a data response_, the only response it should send back is a success/fail indication. If you're using it to retrieve data, you really should consider switching to a GET. Having said that: please use `console.error` for writing your error, and show what the actual error is (there's some text at the top, but that doesn't actually say anything useful: syntax error _for what_?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I change the code according to your suggestion and also updated the code please check it out.

Comment: That new message is still not an error, it's just an object. That's why I told you to use `console.error` for your error, not `console.log`: there is no way to see which of the two possible codepaths that you're passing to `subscribe` are actually kicking in.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I used console.error but I don't get any useful message can you please take a look at it may be you will understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217067/discussion-between-ayush-verma-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).